# R Markdown Unable to Knit to HTML

Tags: r, r-markdown

I've attempted every suggestion from every other thread on this issue that I can find but nothing has worked thus far so I decided to submit my own question. Suddenly my R Markdown file refuses to knit to HTML but seems to be fine knitting to PDF. I keep getting the following error when attempting an HTML knit:

```
List of 10
 $ name      : chr "header-attrs"
 $ version   : chr "2.1"
 $ src       :List of 1
  ..$ file: chr ""
 $ meta      : NULL
 $ script    : chr "header-attrs.js"
 $ stylesheet: NULL
 $ head      : NULL
 $ attachment: NULL
 $ package   : NULL
 $ all_files : logi TRUE
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "html_dependency"
Error: path for html_dependency not found: 
Execution halted
```

Any suggestions as to how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So it looks the knitter can't find the dependency that creates HTML, but it can find your PDF generator. You probably already knew that, but just in case. Has anything changed? Have you upgraded or installed any new components?

Comment: I don't believe that I installed anything between one knit to HTML and the next, at least not that I can recall. I do also get a Directory Not Found message when using the rmarkdown::render command in the console and the Directory does not match my selected Working Directory.

Comment: did you change the working directory recently? If so, maybe change it back and move your data files?

Comment: Okay, I updated the Working Directory and found that the Knit Director was set to "Document Directory". That's now been adjusted so that the Knit Directory is the "Current Working Directory" but the issue is persisting.

Comment: it sounds like the original problem has not been corrected. Maybe reinstall the HTML generator. Or check to confirm that the dependencies directory is correct.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the most effective way to solve the problem, but I uninstalled all packages not included in base R and then reinstalled as needed. It did seem, when doing that, that packages were being installed to a different folder than the correct one which I was able to adjust when I opened R Studio as an admin. From there, I had to reinstall packages by hand but following these steps I was able to knit to HTML again.

Comment: can you share whats in your YAML.?Also how do you knit ? ( crtl+shift + K)  or with the knit button in rStudio or with a function?

Comment: It seems like you found the problem, the bit about the packages being installed in the wrong directory, so that's good. Sometime you just gotta nuke it from orbit and start over.

Comment: @user12256545 My YAML included ```title: "JDM Data"
output:
  html_document:
    code_folding: hide
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 6
  pdf_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: '6' ``` This was the same before and after resetting the install and packages. I was using either the Knit button at the top of the workspace or the Knit command typed into the console.